# Sci-fi book with a main character who finds out he's a clone named Sebring

Tags: story-identification, novel

Trying to find a book whose main character finds out he's a clone and his name is Sebring. I forgot what the other character's name was.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this question by looking at the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), then [edit]ing it to include any further details that come to mind. The more info you can provide, the better the chances that someone will be able to ID this for you.

Comment: Closest I've found is the "Unfinished Hero" series where someone commented that Knight Sebring is a clone of the first book's main character, but that might be nonliteral.

Answer (score -1):

Following because I came here hoping someone already had commented...will update as my hunt continues....
The book is Clones by Gloria Skurzynski!

Comment: This seems not quite the same, since the protagonist is Corgan, not Seabrig.  Can you show how this fits?